# MongoDb C# Driver retrieve Value of increment update

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I make an update with the following inc statement to increase the value of a field

```
 var update = Updates.Inc(x => x.Version, 1);
 await collection.FindAndUpdateOneAsync(myQuery,update);
```

I want to retrieve the new (or old) value from version . Is there a built in way to do so?

Due to Transactional concerns i don't want to make a new seperate query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try `findOneAndUpdate` with `projection` option to return document.

To return old values

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   {},
   { $inc: { Version: 1 } },
   { projection: { Version : 1 }}
)
```

To return updated values, set `returnNewDocument` flag true

```
 db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   {},
   { $inc: { Version: 1 } },
   { projection: { Version : 1 }, returnNewDocument : true  }
 )
```

More here
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: He asked how to do this in C#?

Answer (score 18):

Here is how to do what Veeram said but in c#.

```
        var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<Widget>().Inc(n => n.Version, 1);
        var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Widget>();
        options.ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After;
        options.Projection = new ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<Widget>().Include(n => n.Version);
        var result = col.FindOneAndUpdate<Widget>(n => true, update, options );
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL&DR:**

Use a projection to return the value after an insert:

```
   var opts = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<BsonDocument>()
    {
        ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
    };

var result = await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update, opts);
```

**Explanation**:

MongoDB by default does not return the complete updated value after an insert when you use the FindOneAndUpdateAsync() function.  In order to get the value you have to leverage a projection, which controls the 'output' of a function (in layman terms).

**Full Use Case**

Assume that car_name is a string, that is provided in the function above.  This finds a specific car name, and then updates its country_code, and country_name respectively.

```
    IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = this._database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("cars");
    var filter = new BsonDocument("cars", car_name);
    var opts = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<BsonDocument>()
    {
        ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
    };
    var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("country_name",country_name).Set("country_code",country_code);
    var result = await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update, opts);
    return result;
```

Comment: This is in pure C# :-)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler/another way:

```
var filter = Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Eq("myId", id) 
var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<MyDocument>().Inc(p => p.MyProperty, 1);
await myCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```